# Why do mushrooms freeze in fridge at temps above freezing?

Tags: refrigerator, mushrooms

I noticed mushrooms freeze in my fridge when nothing else does.  Can anybody explain the phenomenon?

Comment: Have you tried storing them in a different spot and storing something else in that position? Sometimes fridges have cold spots.

Comment: it's not so much of a problem, i am still able to cut them, just curious

Comment: What type of mushrooms are they, because ash boletes are still slightly flexible if you freeze them?

Answer (score 7):

Your fridge is infact below freezing temperature, perhaps just slightly. Water (the main liquid in mushrooms) never freezes at temperatures above freezing (0C/32F).

Mushrooms have a lot of surface area and are very light so their temperature can match the fridge easier.  Try placing dry lettuce there and you'll notice the same thing.

If it's a small and not so full fridge, you can raise the temperature a bit.

Comment: Sometimes nature is more complex than that http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1064185883710284

Comment: It is, but that study doesn't show how water can freeze at above freezing, it shows how it may not form ice crystals at below.